# Graphql React mutation doesn't give me a response

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I try to call a graphql mutation from my react application, but I get no response.

In the playground my mutation works

This is how i call the mutation:

```
async getValues(values) {
    const mutation = await this.props.mutate({
      variables: {
        name: values.username,
        email: values.email,
        password: values.password
      }});
}
```

This is my mutation:

```
const registerMutation = gql`
  mutation($name: String!, $email: String!, $password: String!) {
    register(name: $name, email: $email, password: $password) {
      ok
      error
    }
  }
`;
```

I'm sure the the function getValues is called and thet this.props.mutate is a function, but I get no response from it

Comment: show how you call registerMutation in reactjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you dont pass mutation. You need to add this line.

```
mutation = {registerMutation }
```

So it will be something like:

```
async getValues(values) {
    const mutation = await this.props.mutate({
      mutation = {registerMutation } 
      variables: {
        name: values.username,
        email: values.email,
        password: values.password
      }});
```

And also change your const to:

```
const registerMutation = gql`
  mutation registerMutation($name: String!, $email: String!, $password: String!) {
    register(name: $name, email: $email, password: $password) {
      ok
      error
    }
  }
`;
```

If it doesnt help let me know

Comment: If I add ```mutation : registerMutation``` I get the same thing(no response)

Comment: If I add ```mutation : {registerMutation}``` I get an error saying thet I need to pass a graphql document

Comment: If I log the registerMutation it confirms that it is a document

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, when I was connecting to the backend I mistyped the uri

Comment: Okay, I am glad you fix it.